# Python ctypes cannot load DLL if ordinal addresses are in different groups

Tags: python, c, windows, dll, ctypes

I am trying to load a DLL using Python and ctypes. I have built the DLL for x64 successfully using Visual Studio. It is a C library so I do not expect any C++ mangling. There are 24 functions which I wish to expose. I began exposing them one by one by prefixing the function prototypes with `__declspec(dllexport)` in the header file. This was working (tested by loading the DLL with CDLL) until I exposed a certain number of functions. Thereafter I see the following error when loading the DLL:

```
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:28:03) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> mylib = CDLL("MyLib.dll")
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Python27\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 365, in __init__
self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
WindowsError: [Error 182] The operating system cannot run %1
```

I also see a Windows error dialog pop up with:

> The ordinal 4950 could not be located in the dynamic link library

Inspecting with dumpbin I find the following:

```
ordinal hint RVA      name

      1    0 000038A0 my_func_B
      2    1 00002CB0 my_func_G
      3    2 00002E90 my_func_D
      4    3 00003490 my_func_J
      5    4 00003030 my_func_K
      6    5 00003B60 my_func_A
      7    6 00003BE0 my_func_C
      8    7 00002E60 my_func_E
      9    8 00002DF0 my_func_L
     10    9 00003AD0 my_func_H
     11    A 00004000 my_func_F
     12    B 00003C60 my_func_I
     13    C 00003FD0 my_func_O
     14    D 00002D10 my_func_M
     15    E 00002CA0 my_func_N
```

Notice how the Relative Virtual Addresses (RVAs) are higher than 00002xxx. When I remove some of the `__declspec(dllexport)` to go back to a successful python ctypes DLL import state, dumpbin shows me:

```
ordinal hint RVA      name

      1    0 00002810 my_func_B
      2    1 00002490 my_func_G
      3    2 00002670 my_func_D
      4    5 00002640 my_func_A
      5    6 000025D0 my_func_C
      6    7 00002E60 my_func_E
      7    8 00002DF0 my_func_L
      8    9 00002A40 my_func_H
      9    A 00002F70 my_func_F
     10    B 00002BD0 my_func_I
     11    C 000024F0 my_func_O
     12    D 00002480 my_func_M
     13    E 00002CA0 my_func_N
```

Notice how the RVAs are all in the 00002xxx range. I continued to play around and I see the same error if ordinal addresses are mixed with 00001xxx and 00002xxx, but success if I remove function exports such that there are only a handful of addresses in the 00001xxx range.

I can only assume that the error I am seeing is related to this observation. Any ideas?

Comment: The DLL export directory has an array of RVAs to the export names (`AddressOfNames`) and an array of corresponding ordinals (`AddressOfNameOrdinals`) that index into the array of RVAs of the functions (`AddressOfFunctions`). Probably there's a corrupt value in the `AddressOfNameOrdinals` array. Clearly something is wrong with either your installation of Visual Studio or how you're building the DLL.

Comment: Hmmm I have tried tweaking the build (/MT, /MD, optimisations, address randomisations, etc) but to no avail. I will continue tweaking.

Comment: @eryksun Good point. I will try put together something which repros this. Not-related, but in case any one was wondering: building a .so using GCC in Cygwin and importing the library from Python within the Cygwin environment works successfully with all methods exposed (of course no need for __declspec(dllexport) when using GCC)

Comment: @eryksun So I went and stubbed out a C application with 24 functions. Everything was exported correctly using the same build settings. The actual project is of course larger (compiles to a 27 Kb DLL) and links to the OpenSSL static libs. At this point my problem is mitigated by working on Windows with Cygwin, and I have to move on. It is still a mystery to me, and I hope to come back and figure out what is wrong! Thanks for your input.